# How can I place my scene with a background of the Andromeda galaxy

Tags: background, render, imagemap, povray

I'm rather new at povray and I've been struggling with just getting a simple background image behind my rendering. I can create spheres and atmospheres and mapping clouds and surfaces, but I can't make an image simply show up behind my planet.

I've tried the sky_sphere, I've tried putting an infinite plane behind the planet but the Andromeda image_map will not just map as it is. It's either distorted, or zoomed in so close a single star is the size of a dime, or the stars are lines radiating out like I'm making the jump to light speed. There's got to be the right combination of map_type, scaling and translate that will get me what I want but I haven't found it yet.

I'm assuming this is a simple thing for anyone with experience.

I'm after something like this:

[image]